# Error in parameter conversion using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function template that takes a vector and an element of a given type and returns the position of the element in the vector. This is the code for this function template:

```
template<class T>
int findElement(const vector<T> &vec, const T &ele)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ele == vec[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And here's the function call:

```
findElement<double>(intVec, ele);
```

But I get this error when I call the function:

```
error C2664: 'findElement' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &'
```

And this error is same even if I remove the `const` for the vector in the function template definition:

```
error C2664: 'findElement' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &'
```

However, when I make the function call as

```
findElement(intVec, ele)
```

I do not get any error.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: What are the types of `intVec` and `ele`?

Comment: intVec and ele are both of type int. But I want the compiler to treat them as double when instantiating the template function.

Comment: @RakeshK Why?  Treating them as doubles would not change what `findElement` does.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like compiler cannot convert `vector<double>` to `vector<int>`. Since by logic way, `intVec` is vector of ints, isn't it? And you say compiler, that you want `vector` of doubles.
You cannot convert `vector<T>` to `vector<U>`, since `vector` has no following `conversion constructor`, and it's nice.